# Active/deactive button in PHP with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I'm trying to create a admin page. I have a checkbox which represents the activeness of the post for my blog page.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB7s5.png)

When I click on checkbox, I want to change the isActive value of the post in database instantly. I don't want to use html forms either.

I've tried ajax jquery but It also doesn't work..

I've put a onclick tag inside of a checkbox. When I click the checkbox, It executes the

clicked() function with 2 parameters (which are postid and isActive). I want to send these parameters with post method to the same page again so i can determine which post should i work on.

Here are my codes...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function clicked(postid, isActive){
    $.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'admin-posts.php', 
    data: {tpi: "{$postid}"},
    success: function(resp){
       console.log("Finished. " + resp); 
    },
    error : function(err){
        console.log("Error: " + err); 
    }   
});



}

</script>
```

Update:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3zKx.png

I hope I made my problem more clear.

Comment: *"but It also doesn't work"* - Can you be more specific?  In what way is it failing?  If you're not familiar with your browser's debugging tools or with PHP debugging, now is the time to start.

Comment: Did you check if the first request was blocked by the browser for CORS violation?

Comment: You need to ensure that both postid and isActive are sent in the request. Also, make sure that the postid variable is not enclosed in quotes because it's a JavaScript variable. postid: postid, isActive: isActive

Answer (score 0):

You may confuse about JavaScript variable and PHP variable. According to your code the parameter should be like...

data: {tpi: postid}

But you are trying with

data: {tpi: "{$postid}"}

Comment: data : {tpi: postid} doesn't work either...